# Win7 admin disabled, had a password, cannot enable

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I enabled the administrator user, then put a password on it, then disabled it! And the other user is a standard one. How can I enabled my administrator account again?

Comment: Did You have enabled built-in Administrator account? by typing command: net user administrator /active:yes ?

Comment: I am not sure from your question if you mean the built in 'Administrator' account or one you have created your self.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the first thing to do would be to boot into [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) and see if the administrator account appears.

If so, then log into that account and create a new user account with admin privileges.

If the Administrator account does not appear then you need to re-enable it by booting up the computer with the windows installation CD then,
Select the Default Language, "Repair Your Computer" then choose "Command Prompt".
At the command prompt type:

net user administrator /active:yes [enter]

Remove the DVD, reboot the computer, and log into the built-in Administrator account.

[I found the answer from this source.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/lost-administrator-account-on-windows-7/62a99dcc-b976-4ad1-9ac5-e7bf803eab83) I recommended reading the full answer here has it is more thorough and tells you what to do if you don't have a windows installation CD.

Comment: This is the answer I was going to write. Good job.